# elasticsearch how to find number of occurrences

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder if it's possible to convert this sql query into ES query?
**select top 10 app, cat, count(*) from err group by app, cat**

Or in English it would be answering: "Show top app, cat and their counts", so this will be grouping by multiple fields and returning name and count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For aggregating on a combination of multiple fields, you have to use scripting in `Terms Aggregation` like below:

```
POST <index name>/<type name>/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "app_cat": {
      "terms": {
        "script" : "doc['app'].value + '#' + doc['cat'].value",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using `#` as a delimiter assuming that it is not present in any value of `app` and/or `cat` fields. You can use any other delimiter of your choice. You'll get a response something like below:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 10,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "app_cat": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "app2#cat2",
               "doc_count": 4
            },
            {
               "key": "app1#cat1",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "app2#cat1",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "app1#cat2",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

On the client side, you can get the individual values of `app` and `cat` fields from the aggregation response by string manipulations.

In newer versions of Elasticsearch, scripting is disabled by default due to security reasons. If you want to enable scripting, read [this](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html).

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. One more question.Is there a way to suppress inside "hits" to get back only what your output shows?{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 10,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []         **< ======= to suppress everything inside "[]" like here**
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "app_cat": {
         "buckets": ...........

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of the `hits` section in response.

Answer (score 1):

[Terms aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've tried this:{
  "aggregations": {
    "app_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "app"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "cat_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "cat"
          }          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, but it did not work. Also, does it have to be _search or _count query?

Comment: For aggregation , either of them will do.